# Pass dynamic params to IIFE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

I've got this issue with passing a variable to an IFFE. did some reading, still didn't figure it out. would really appreciate some guidance here.

- i have a click event handler function that gets a certain ID from the
  DOM when clicked.
- i need to pass that ID to an IIFE
- that IFFE needs to either add/remove  that ID from an array,
  depending if it's already there or not.

This is what I got:

**Event:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', check);
```

**Click Handler:**

```
function check() {
    var id = $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-id');
    return id;
}
```

**IIFE:**

```
var checkID = (function (val) {

    var arr = [];

    return function () {

        var i = arr.indexOf(val);

        if (i === -1) {
            arr.push(val);
        } else {

            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }

})(id);
```

right now i'm getting the ID, but returning it to nowhere.

in my IIFE, i did pass an `id` variable, but it's undefined.

so, how do I pass the `ID` variable im getting from `check()` to `checkID` IIFE?

other solutions are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to to be an IIFE - what you need is a simple F(unction). And in any case your function will always just return an array with a single element - you create the array at the beginning of the outer function.

Comment: a normal function would reset my array whenever it runs. if i'm missing something, please clarify.

Comment: So you want each click to remember the array, I get that. but where do you expect that array to be returned *to*? The click will never return any data.

Comment: you're right, i should have mentioned i need that array too. luckily your answer covers that :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do things sort of the other way around. Your `check` function would return a function used by the event handler, but it would also take a callback to be called after the click handler has run, passing your array.

The `check` function would look like a mash-up of both your functions:

```
function check(callback){
  var arr = [];
  return function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-id');
    var i = arr.indexOf(id);

    if (i === -1) {
        arr.push(id);
    } else {

        arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
    callback(arr);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it takes as a parameter a callback function, which will be called on each execution, passing the current array `arr`. For example, this is my test callback:

```
function handler(arr){
 alert("Array has " + arr.length + " elements");
}
```

Finally, your event handler would look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', check(handler));
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/src282d6/

Comment: so by referencing to an outer function's variable from my inner function i keep the array alive, but what does JS do with `arr = []`, the second, third, fourth.. time i call the outer function? ignores it? i'd expect it to reset the array. if you could elaborate that would be awesome.

Comment: @Uzi there is one `arr` for each unique time you call `check`. It works fine when applying event handlers once for all checkboxes, or similar, like you're doing. But if you added another line `$(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', check(handler));` (for example) that would have a *different instance of `arr`* - the radios and checkboxes would know nothing about each other's separate array of checked id's.

Answer (score 2):

In your clickHandler

```
function check() {
    var id = $(this).closest('ul').attr('data-id');
    checkID(id);
}
```

and change `checkID` to

```
var checkID = (function () {

    var arr = [];

    return function (val) {

        var i = arr.indexOf(val);

        if (i === -1) {
            arr.push(val);
        } else {

            arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return arr;
    }

})();
```

Comment: This works great! thank you! although @Jamiec showed a better solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using getter/setter-like functions in your IIFE function makes it much more organized and readable. Then, use these functions to pass, store, and read data across your IIFE function.

```
var checkID = (function () {
    // your array
    var arr = [];
    // public
    return { 
      // get
      getArray: function(){
        return arr;
      },
      // set value
      setArray: function(val) {
        var i = arr.indexOf(val);
        if (i === -1) {
          arr.push(val);
        } else {
          arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
})();
```

Use it as follows:

```
checkID.getArray(); // returns default empty array []
checkID.setArray('car1');
checkID.setArray('car2');
checkID.setArray('car3');
checkID.setArray('car4');
checkID.setArray('car4'); // test splice()
checkID.getArray(); // returns ["car1", "car2", "car3"]
```